# How to use FirefoxDriver locally and RemoteWebDriver on CI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, playframework-2.3

I'm using playframework 2.3.

Is there a convenient way to use `FirefoxDriver` locally and a `RemoteWebDriver` when the test runs on a CI env (Travis) ?

After some effort, I've come on with an helper trait :

```
trait EnvAwareDriver {
  def driver(): WebDriver = {
    if (System.getenv("CI") == "true") {
      WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)
    } else {
      val caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
      caps.setCapability("platform", "Linux")
      caps.setCapability("version", "32 .0")
      caps.setCapability("tunnelIdentifier", System.getenv("TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER"))
      new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("…"), caps)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've came up with a cleaner solution, by extracting the logic in a `trait`

```
trait EnvAwareDriver {
  def localDrivers: Seq[String => WebDriver]
  def remoteDrivers: Seq[String => WebDriver]

  def drivers: Seq[String => WebDriver] = if (System.getenv("CI") != "true") localDrivers else remoteDrivers
}
```